# Search for a user input word in an array by using a counter

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

What I am trying to do is create a program that has a set array, the program asks the user to input a word, the program finds the word and outputs how many times it is used. So for example the array I have set up (each letter is in its own array number) is "The theory of thermon" because it has a couple of 'the' in text. I want the user to input 'the' and have the output to be 2 (because the first is uppercase). Or if the user wanted to input 'e' he would get 3.

I have the array setup, but am still looking for a way to setup the program so it can look at more than one letter at a time if the user inputs more than one letter.

I am assuming that I need to input a .length for the scanner, input the counter around that, and have the array move along with that. I'll look more into this, if you guys could give me a hand I would appreciate.

Edit

```
public class SearchableSentence {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

double count = 0;   

String[] stringer = {"T","h","e"," ","t","h","e","o","r","y"," ","o","f"," ","T","h","e","o"," ","i","s"," ","t","h","a","t"," ","t","h","e"," ","o","t","h","e","r"," ","t","h","i","n","g","s"," ","a","r","e"," ","a"," ","b","o","t","h","e","r","."};
```

Comment: Have you produced any code yet?

Comment: Would be nice to see some code. We're here to help you, not to make your homework :).

Comment: share your code snippet. so that we can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do what you expect. I have not tested it though.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class DoWork {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
        String[] myStringArray = {"The", "theory", "of", "thermon"};
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String searchTerm = br.readLine();
        int counter=0;
        for (String s: myStringArray) {
            if (s.contains(searchTerm)){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```